# Ionic Expandable/ Accordion List

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Please help me, I want to create a simple accordion in ionic 5
I had created ionic accordion list by following a tutorial blog link that used widgets for creating an accordion dropdowns, Below is the link of that blog…
https://masteringionic.com/blog/2019-01-27-creating-a-simple-accordion-widget-in-ionic-4/

The problem is no list appears and no error is shown

[image: accordion output]

This is my .html file

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Accordion
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <app-accordion 
     *ngFor="let technology of technologies" 
     name="{{ technology.name }}" 
     description="{{ technology.description }}"
     (change)="captureName($event)">
  </app-accordion>
</ion-content>
```

**mi-accordion.component.html**

```
<h2 (click)="toggleAccordion()">
  {{ name }}
   <span *ngIf="isMenuOpen">&#9650;</span>
   <span *ngIf="!isMenuOpen">&#9660;</span>
</h2>
<div [ngClass]="this.isMenuOpen ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
   <p>{{ description }}</p>
   <ion-button 
      type="button" 
      color="primary" 
      fill="solid" 
      size="default" 
      (click)="broadcastName(name)">Console log me!</ion-button>
</div>
```

Can someone help if I am missing something? And please tell me if you need others code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolved this by changing the mi-accordion.component.html to

```
  <app-mi-accordion 
     *ngFor="let technology of technologies" 
     name="{{ technology.name }}" 
     description="{{ technology.description }}"
     (change)="captureName($event)">
  </app-mi-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

My accordion  is like this:

In html i created cards using ngFor "any other component will work" , and i added the css class "myHiddenTec" to all sub-element that should be initially hidden, in this case "ion-card-content".
Also, i added two icons, the second one is initially hidden, one calls "iconWork(p.id+'' )" and the second calls "revIconWork(p.id+'')" and i pass any unique key of my objoct "post.id".
My trick is to add constant string to the element id like "p.id+'content'" or "p.id+'icon'" and so on.

html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of posts">
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
        </ion-card-header>

        <ion-card-content [id]="p.id+'content'" class="myHiddenTec">
        </ion-card-content>

        <ion-icon [id]="p.id" color="primary" name="add-outline"
            (click)="iconWork(p.id+'' )"></ion-icon>
            
        <ion-icon [id]="p.id+'icon2'"  class="myHiddenTec" name="remove-outline"
            (click)="revIconWork(p.id+'')"></ion-icon>
    </ion-card>
</ng-container>
```

css

```
.myHiddenTec{
    display: none;
}
```

ang.ts

```
iconWork(id: string ){
    let icon1 = document.getElementById(id);
    icon1.style.display = "none";

    let icon2 = document.getElementById(id+'icon2');
    icon2.style.display = "block";
    
    let content = document.getElementById(id+'content');
    content.style.display = "block";
    
  }

  revIconWork(id: string ){
    let icon1 = document.getElementById(id);
    icon1.style.display = "block";

    let icon2 = document.getElementById(id+'icon2');
    icon2.style.display = "none";

    let content = document.getElementById(id+'content');
    content.style.display = "none";
  }
```